# Create array of string addresses (data elements) in NASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Suppose I've an 3-element array in NASM

`strings: dw 0x00, 0x00, 0x00`

, that I want to fill with addresses of strings, also defined within the `.data` section, e.g.,

`hello_word: db "HelloWorld!", 0`.

Writing  `strings: dw hello_world, 0x00, 0x00` is a syntax error.

How do I populate an array with addresses, so that I can loop over it at runtime, each time incrementing the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, "-f coff"! Make your addresses `dd` not `dw`.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
segment data
 prompt_msg db "Input a string: ",0
 output_msg db "The reverse is: ",0

 stringPtr dw prompt_msg
           dw output_msg

 -->

0734:0100  49 6E 70 75 74 20 61 20-73 74 72 69 6E 67 3A 20 Input a string:
0734:0110  00 54 68 65 20 72 65 76-65 72 73 65 20 69 73 3A .The reverse is:
0734:0120  20 00 00 00 11
```

at 0x121: `00 00` and `00 11` are the two pointers to the strings

Comment: Weird, I get output: base.asm:30: error: COFF format does not support non-32-bit relocations
base.asm:31: error: COFF format does not support non-32-bit relocations

Comment: sounds like you try to store 32bit adresses in 16bit values. what OS are you using?

Comment: Exactly, that was my problem... Thank you. I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You could also load the effective addresses of the strings at runtime using the LEA instruction (x86):

```
lea eax, [_str1]
mov [_s_table], eax
lea eax, [_str2]
mov [_s_table + 0x04], eax
lea eax, [_str3]
mov [_s_table + 0x08], eax
```

But, probably, Frank Kotler's approach is better.